# c++: variable 'f' not initialized

Tags: c++

I'm creating a text-based Risk game on C++. Been trying to implement the dice / battle function but it's been giving me the error "f is used without being initialized!" Which is weird because I initialized it earlier. Here's my code

```
void battle(int attack, int defend)
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, f;

    if (attack >= 3)
    {
        a = rollDice();
        b = rollDice();
        c = rollDice();
    }

    else if (attack == 2)
    {
        a = rollDice();
        b = rollDice();
        c = 0;
    }

    else if (attack == 1)
    {
        a = rollDice();
        b = 0;
        c = 0;
    }

    else if (defend >= 2)
    {
        d = rollDice();
        e = rollDice();
        f = 0;
    }

    else if (defend == 1)
    {
        d = rollDice();
        e = 0;
        f = 0;
    }

    sortValues(a, b, c);
    sortValues(d, e, f);

    cout << endl << "The attacking country rolled the following dices: " << a
            << " " << b << " " << c << ".";
    cout << endl << "The defending country rolled the following dices: " << d
            << " " << e << " " << f << ".";

    if (a == d)
    {
        attack = attack - 1;
    }

    else if (a != d)
    {
        if (a < d)
        {
            attack = attack - 1;
        }

        else if (a > d)
        {
            defend = defend - 1;
        }
    }

    else if (b == e)
    {
        attack = attack - 1;
    }

    else if (b != e)
    {
        if (b < e)
        {
            attack = attack - 1;
        }

        else if (b > e)
        {
            defend = defend - 1;
        }
    }

// since the int f is never used, this function is critical to implement. so that we can avoid compile time error
    _unused(f);
}

int main()
{

    int attack;
    int defend;
    int choice;

// this asks for the user choice of what he would like to do. 

    cout << "How large is the attacking army?" << endl;
    cin >> attack;
    cout << "How large is the defending army?" << endl;
    cin >> defend;

    while (attack >= 1 && defend >= 1)
    {
        cout
                << "Based on the numbers you entered, you have a couple of choices: "
                << endl << endl;

        cout << "1) Battle once" << endl;
        cout << "2) Battle until the end" << endl;
        cout << "3) Withdraw from the battle" << endl;

        cout << "Please enter your game choice (just enter the number): "
                << endl;
        cin >> choice;

        if (choice == 1)
        {
            battle(attack, defend);
        }

        if (choice == 2)
        {
            do
            {
                battle(attack, defend);
            } while (attack != 0 && defend != 0);

            cout << "Battle ended. The attacking forces are: " << attack
                    << " , while the defending forces are: " << defend << endl;
        }

        if (choice == 3)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (attack < 1)
    {
        cout
                << "The attacking forces have lost. Defending forces keep their territory"
                << endl;
    }

    else if (defend < 1)
    {
        cout << "The attacking forces have won over the territory." << endl;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

This isn't all of the code, but it's the critical section which includes and uses f.

Comment: A couple side notes: 1) Declaring multiple variables in one line can be a dangerous habit to have, as what happens doesn't always match what looks like should happen. `int* a, b, c;` declares one pointer to an int and two ints, rather than declaring three pointers to ints. 2) `dice` is the plural of `die`, as in the thing often rolled in games. `dices` is a verb relating to cutting things.

Answer (score 0):

In the `battle` function you are calling `sortValues(d,e,f)`, but in the first 3 if-cases `f` does not get a value (thus is not initialized).

Actually you should get a similar error (is it really an error or a warning?) for `d` and in some of the cases you do not give a value to `a`,`b` and `c`.

Comment: i only got an error for f! i changed the sort values parameters to (int& a, int& b, int& c); 

and it works .. sorta. the defending position is spawning weird dice rolls

Comment: I didnt comment on the rest of your code, because I dont really get it. Actually your `battle` function has zero effect. It returns nothing and it only modifies local variables. I guess when passing `atttack` and `defend` you actually meant to pass references. At the moment the variable `attack` in the main and the variable `attack` in `battle()` have nothing in common but their names.

Comment: @MajdKhoury I read your code again, and honestly, there are too many problems to discuss them all in my answer (when the actual question was only about noninitialized `f`). I suggest you to start with something much simpler (less code) and first make sure you got it right, before adding more.

Comment: solid advice. I redid it again and it works perfectly. Thank you.